# Socket on Android mobile

Tags: android, sockets

Can Android Mobile open a socket With Python PC Server Code ?? i did a code but the android code only connect in the Emulator Is this due to i have to change any thing  in my Mobile to be able to connect socket

Answer (score 1):

> Can Android Mobile open a socket With Python PC Server Code ??

Android neither knows nor cares what language is used for the server.

> i did a code but the android code only connect in the Emulator Is this due to i have to change any thing in my Mobile to be able to connect socket

No. Bear in mind, though, that your phone may or may not be able to talk to the server for other reasons:

- If you are on mobile data (e.g., 3G), if the server is not on the public Internet, you will not be able to reach it
- If you are on WiFi, and the server is only listening on localhost, you will not be able to reach it

Both of those will be problems with your server implementation and deployment. Android has nothing to do with it.

Comment: so how can my mobile be able to connect with a server ??

Comment: @eoeo: Write and deploy a server someplace where the phone can reach it. That has nothing to do with Android.